# "Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value" while using React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to debug validation errors from an application using the [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) library.

The code is quite simple but when I submit the form the app crashed due to an `Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value` error.

This is the minimal reproducible example.

```
function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input
        {...register("firstName", {
          required: true,
          maxLength: 20,
          pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
        })}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(errors)}</pre>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [very common problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) not linked with react-use-form itself.

The JSON format doesn't support object references, so `JSON.stringify()` fails when it tries to stringify an object with circular references.

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(errors)}</pre>
```

Unfortunately, browsers don't have a function like Node's [utils.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) which is able to deal with references without failing.

You can use an [external library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-inspect) to log the `errors` object, or just use react-use-form errors properly:

```
      <input
        {...register("firstName", {
          required: true,
          maxLength: 20,
          pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
        })}
      />
      {errors?.firstName?.type === "required" && <p>This field is required</p>}
      {errors?.firstName?.type === "maxLength" && (
        <p>First name cannot exceed 20 characters</p>
      )}
      {errors?.firstName?.type === "pattern" && (
        <p>Alphabetical characters only</p>
      )}
```

There is also a [dedicated React component named](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hookform/error-message)  to show easily react-form-hook errors without conditional rendering.

```
  <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="singleErrorInput" />

  <ErrorMessage
    errors={errors}
    name="singleErrorInput"
    render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
  />
```